# pytest test for running jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My task is to write a python code (pytest test) in .py file, which runs jupyter notebook and asserts that output is 1.

I have method for running notebook:

```
def _notebook_run(path):
    args = ["jupyter", "nbconvert", "--execute", path]
    a = subprocess.check_call(args)
    return a
```

And a test:

```
def test_test():
    a = _notebook_run('./file.ipynb') 
    assert a == 1
```

when I run it with this test it returns 0, although, when I run jupyter notebook separately it returns 1 as expected.

Why is the output different?

Did I make some mistake in method, which runs notebook?

Can somebody help?

**UPDATE:**
As I've figured out it always returns 0, no matter what code is executed in notebook.
Does someone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed method and got the needed result:

```
def test_file(self):
        result = os.popen("jupyter nbconvert --to script --execute --stdout file.ipynb | python3").read()
        assert result == '1\n'
```

reason of my error was that method used always returns 0, but not the output from the command.